# RQT Custom Plugin: undefined symbol

Tags: plugin, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am trying to have a simple RQT template to use in the future whenever I need to create a new GUI.
The main idea of my minimal (not) working example [(MNWE)](https://github.com/marco-tranzatto/rqt_template_plugin) is to have:

- TemplatePlugin class that is exported as plugin for RQT;
- TemplateWidget class that implements an RQT widget that is then included in TemplatePlugin.

This is a similar approach employed in [rqt_multiplot](https://github.com/ethz-asl/rqt_multiplot_plugin) where there's one main MultiplotPlugin that includes different widgets.

I'm able to compile my [(MNWE)](https://github.com/marco-tranzatto/rqt_template_plugin) , but when I launch the gui I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1511538332.555287110]: Failed to load nodelet [rqt_template_plugin::TemplatePlugin_0] of type [rqt_template_plugin::TemplatePlugin]: Failed to load library /home/marco/catkin_ws/devel/lib//librqt_template_plugin.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /home/marco/catkin_ws/devel/lib//librqt_template_plugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN19rqt_template_plugin14TemplatePluginD1Ev)

RosPluginlibPluginProvider::load_explicit_type(rqt_template_plugin::TemplatePlugin) failed creating instance PluginManager._load_plugin() could not load plugin "rqt_template_plugin::TemplatePlugin": RosPluginlibPluginProvider.load() could not load plugin "rqt_template_plugin::TemplatePlugin"
```

Even though the error suggests that I don't have the macro "PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS", it is actually present in my cpp file: [PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS](https://github.com/marco-tranzatto/rqt_template_plugin/blob/master/rqt_template_plugin/src/rqt_template_plugin/TemplatePlugin.cpp#L44).
So I guess I am not linking the plugin at compile time correctly and then having issue at run time. I tried the solution proposed in this other thread [question/215487](https://answers.ros.org/question/215487/could-not-load-panel-in-rviz-pluginlibfactory-the-plugin-for-class/), but adding "set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)" to make CMakeLists.txt file prevents me compiling the whole package.

**Update of 27/11/2017**

Running the command

```
for f in $(find ~/catkin_ws -name "*.so"); do echo $f; objdump -TC $f | grep _ZN19rqt_template_plugin14TemplatePluginD1Ev; done
```

the symbol "_ZN19rqt_template_plugin14TemplatePluginD1Ev" is not found at all. Whereas if I run the command

```
for f in $(find ~/catkin_ws -name "*.so"); do echo $f; objdump -TC $f | grep rqt_template_plugin; done
```

Then I obtain:

```
/home/marco/catkin_ws/devel/lib/librqt_template_plugin.so
/home/marco/catkin_ws/devel/lib/librqt_template_plugin.so:     file format elf64-x86-64
0000000000000000      D  *UND*  0000000000000000              
rqt_template_plugin::TemplatePlugin::~TemplatePlugin()
0000000000000000      D  *UND*  0000000000000000              
rqt_template_plugin::TemplatePlugin::~TemplatePlugin()
0000000000000000      D  *UND*  0000000000000000              non-virtual thunk to 
rqt_template_plugin::TemplatePlugin::~TemplatePlugin()
0000000000000000      D  *UND*  0000000000000000              non-virtual thunk to 
rqt_template_plugin::TemplatePlugin::~TemplatePlugin()
```

** End Update **

I was wondering if anyone could give me a hint about what I should try next.

Thanks a lot,

Marco.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276638/rqt-custom-plugin:-undefined-symbol/) by [Femer](https://answers.ros.org/users/26134/femer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 253 on 2017-11-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2017-11-24**:
Not an answer but maybe helps. You can see if the symbol exists in any library on your `catkin_ws` with:

`for f in $(find ~/catkin_ws -name "*.so"); do echo $f; objdump -TC $f | grep _ZN19rqt_template_plugin14TemplatePluginD1Ev; done`

If is defined, it will be printed after the name of the `.so`

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2017-11-24**:
If you see that the symbol is defined, then is just because it's not being loaded at runtime.

See if the path to the library is on your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with: `env | grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

**Comment by [Femer](https://answers.ros.org/users/26134/femer/) on 2017-11-27**:
Hi Ruben, thanks for your comment! With your first command the symbol was not found at all. Instead if I grep rqt_template then I get the result I just pasted in the updated question ... any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Femer !

The problem is that you missed the implementation of the destructor.  You can solve just by defining `TemplatePlugin::~TemplatePlugin(){}` on your [TemplatePlugin.cpp](https://github.com/marco-tranzatto/rqt_template_plugin/blob/master/rqt_template_plugin/src/rqt_template_plugin/TemplatePlugin.cpp).

I've discovered this by running  `c++filt _ZN19rqt_template_plugin14TemplatePluginD1Ev` that give us the following output:
`rqt_template_plugin::TemplatePlugin::~TemplatePlugin()`.

I've created a video (https://youtu.be/4xZKflNlJho) that shows that this was the only problem.

Ruben.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Femer](https://answers.ros.org/users/26134/femer/) on 2017-11-28**:
Awesome! That was it! Thanks for spotting this!